# How to build static property that is aware of inheritance chain in PHP without boilerplate

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have been struggling to implement an OOP concept in PHP, and the solution is eluding me. I have an abstract base class whose constructor calls a series of setters in a dispatch table based on an associative array of argument data, as follows:

```
abstract class Base {
    protected static $_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL = array();

    public function __construct(array $data) {
        foreach (static::$_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL as $dataKey => $method) {
            if (array_key_exists($dataKey, $data)) {
                if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
                    $this->$method($data[$dataKey]);
                }
                else {
                    // Handle error
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is be able to define a method in my base class that builds the setter dispatch table by merging the subclass' dispatch table with that of each of its parents, so I would be able to do this:

```
class Foo extends Base {
    protected static $_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL = array('foo' => 'setFoo');
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    protected static $_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL = array('bar' => 'setBar');
    // The base constructor should call setFoo() and setBar()
}

class Baz extends Bar {
    protected static $_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL = array('baz' => 'setBaz');
    // The base constructor should call setFoo(), setBar(), and setBaz()
}
```

I can't figure out a way to define this behavior in the base class and make it take into account everything that happens all the way down the inheritance chain. The only way I've been able to come up with to do what I'm trying to do is to create a second property that contains the setters the class wishes to add to the model, and add this boilerplate constructor to each subclass:

```
public function __construct(array $data) {
    if (!array_key_exists(
        key(self::$_SUPPLEMENTAL_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL),
        static::$_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL
    )) {
        static::$_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL = array_merge(
            static::$_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL,
            self::$_SUPPLEMENTAL_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL
        );
    }
    parent::__construct($data);
}
```

There has to be a better way to do this, right?

Comment: What exactly is the endgoal here? Do you need to be able to add new properties during runtime, or can you treat $_SETTER_DISPATCH_MODEL as final? Secondly why do you need to create a dispatch table in a dynamic language? Why not just implement the required methods and do method_exists test?

Comment: The purpose of the base class is to represent a generic object returned from a REST API. The idea is to have the base class handle all the work of inspecting the data returned by the API and calling the appropriate setters to instantiate a representation of it, and in the subclasses, I just define the methods and set up the key/method associations in the dispatch table. I want to have several levels of inheritance, e.g. GenericAPIObject (contains an ID) -> GenericNamedAPIObject (contains an ID and a name) -> (so forth).